# Expo - increase location accuracy with Geofence

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, expo

I could really use some help improving the accuracy of the Geofencing feature. If you look at the following screenshots you can see my location and the location of circle and marker which share the same latLng coordiantes and radius as my geofence.

[Link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t03A.png)

If I run the following lines within the `app.js` file:

```
const taskName = "front_door";
const latLng = { latitude: -37.820711, longitude: 144.994264 };
const radius = 5;

Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);

Location.startGeofencingAsync(taskName, [
  {
    ...latLng,
    radius
  }
]);

TaskManager.defineTask(taskName, task => {
  if (task.data.eventType === Location.GeofencingEventType.Enter) {
    console.log("entered");
  }
  console.log(task.data.region.state);
  return;
});
```

Which is returning `entered` and `1` ([explanation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/sdk/location/#locationgeofencingregionstate)).
Given my current location being outside of the geofence I would expect `entered` to fire only once I had inside of the geofence and `task.data.region.state` to equal `2` ([explanation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/sdk/location/#locationgeofencingregionstate)).

If I change:

```
const latLng = { latitude: -37.820711, longitude: 144.994264 };
```

To:

```
const latLng = { latitude: -37, longitude: 144 };
```

The geofence is far enough away that `entered` is never output and the `task.data.region.state` equals 2.

This leads me to believe that the issue is related to the accuracy set of `Location` however, I cannot find a way to increase the accuracy when using the `startGeofencingAsync` method.

If I was not using geofencing I would do something like this:

```
Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(taskName, { 
    accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest 
});
```

But I can't see how to access the options object when using `Location.startGeofencingAsync(taskName, regions)`

If you know how to achieve this please do let me know as I am pulling my hair out over it! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: alex did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Response from Expo team member: 
"Hi @ahvmckay!

Unfortunately, I don’t think you can fiddle with the accuracy on geofencing :frowning_face:

Although- feel free to look at the Location module source code 12 to investigate for yourself"

https://forums.expo.io/t/geofence-location-accuracy-option/23967/2?u=ahvmckay